# mvccontrib portable area content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

I am on a team with some other folks working on an asp.net mvc2 web app and are utilizing portable areas from the mvccontrib library to seperate sections of our app into different projects. My question is: is it possible to access images, .css and .js files that are inside the portable area? and if so how?

we tried embedding them as resources but where unsure how to access them from our views, so for right now we have them in the container project but it drives us crazy having code and resources for a function scattered between projects.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what i was looking for [Here](http://groups.google.com/group/mvccontrib-discuss/browse_thread/thread/b5f9c77f3a7523ff?pli=1)